# Enable/Disable button in the gridx

Tags: javascript, dojo, gridx

I am trying to set several button disabled in the gridx. (Using dojo gridx 1.3)
The button in the gridx has two state(enable state and disabled) and it changes based on the conditions. 
I am investigating CellWidget demo now. But I could not find the good way to set the states of button in the gridx.
http://oria.github.io/gridx/demos/cellWidget.html

Is it possible to disable the specific button in the gridx.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to disable the button in the CellWidget.
"disbaled" property can disable the button.
Thank you.

```
this.btn.set('disabled', true);
```